# why are link, style and script elements moved from head to body by browsers erroneously?

Tags: html, dom, browser

The problem:  When I place link, style or script elements in the head element then the browsers appear to  erroneously move these elements into the body element as detected by walking the JavaScript node tree. By erroneously I mean that they violate the specification. For example http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-link-element which states:

> Note: If the rel attribute is used, the element is restricted to the head element.

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>head test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />.
    <link href="sample.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <script></script>
    <style>p{font-family:"Times New Roman";font-size:20px;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>test paragraph</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function htmlTree(obj){
        var obj = obj || document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
        var str = "<ul><li>" + obj.tagName;
        if (obj.hasChildNodes()) {
            var child = obj.firstChild;
            while (child) {
                if (child.nodeType === 1) {
                    str += htmlTree(child)
                }
            child = child.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    str += "</li></ul>";
    return str;
}
window.onload=document.write(htmlTree());
```

and here is the result:

```
HTML
    HEAD
        TITLE
        META
    BODY
        LINK
        SCRIPT
        STYLE
        P
        SCRIPT
```

Note that the link, script, and style elements that were in the head have been moved to the body while the title and meta elements are correct. Unfortunately  this has become an issue with me because when I use HTML5 contentedible and move elements the elements get all jumbled up and cannot be untangled. Since html5 supports class attributes on these elements I'm wondering if I could use a "headtype" class to distinguish these specific elements.

This is somewhat similar to [Webkit moves head content to body, and adds extra space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856573/webkit-moves-head-content-to-body-and-adds-extra-space) but more detailed. That question was specific to WebKit but I have tested this in WebKit, Chrome, IE, and Firefox and get the same results in each browser which puzzles me.

Since all the major browsers have the same behavior I suspect I misunderstand something and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Just noticing (probably unrelated or maybe even html5?) But your script and style tags have no type attribute.

Comment: You've got a character (dot) after the `<meta>` tag. That means the start of `<body>`, thus the end of `</head>`.

Comment: @RobW: Spot on. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: @TimDown I've voted to close as TL. I don't expect that anyone will ever find this question through Google with the correct search terms.

Comment: @RobW: Good point, I agree.

Comment: @RobW i actually have landed here from "head element move" googling and had spared myself head pain;  if it was the only argument for closing as too localized, i suggest to lift it. thanks

Comment: @RobW I landed here as well trying to find out why my links and scripts jumped out of my head into my body. I don't see an answer in this thread that solves my problem.

Answer (score 4):

After some more investigation trying to characterize the parameters of the problem more succinctly I found the problem. After doing a hex dump of the HTML file of the file I had copied for my test case I found some hidden control characters after the meta tag that displayed as a dot as Rob W noticed. After removing the control characters the HTML worked correctly. Since I am constrained to use HTML generated elsewhere it looks like I'll have to preprocess the HTML prior to loading the browser.