# HTML head content such as CSS and Javascript links are moved to the top of body

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, head

I am doing a website and its pages has the following structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
        <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

                Javascript and CSS links are here

                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->
        </head>

  <body class="ns-0" id="bodyId">

  page content is here

  </body>
</html>
```

However, when the page is loaded, all the content inside  is moved to the top of  tag. Besides, the page top has some white space, which should not happen by design.

I found this link at SO

[Webkit moves head content to body, and adds extra space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856573/webkit-moves-head-content-to-body-and-adds-extra-space)

and I tried its solution, but the problem still exists after I removed Byte-Order Mask (BOM). I see this issue in IE, Chrome, and FF (I have these browsers on my computer).

Any idea about what I should try?

Thanks!

Edit: this is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The comments on the answer for the included question is that a bug was raised. That's now been closed. Maybe open a new bug, doesn't look like anything was done about it though

Comment: You should include a screenshot

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: What is your actual code? As is it, your text "Javascript and CSS links are here" is going to trigger the start of the body.

Comment: Within the [`head`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head) metadata content is allowed only. Are you sure there's no script adding other than [metadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Metadata_content) tag(s) to the `head`? Such a tag would implicitely end the `head` parsing, and set a starting `body`, and place all the remained code to the `body`.